# UITextField editing and adding to array

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, nsmutablearray, uitextfield

Okay so i have a series of UITextFields that have the tags between 21 and 35. I am using the               UITextField delegate to get the value of the textfield when its finished editing and then adds it to a mutable array. The code for the delegate method is as follows:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

if(textField.tag >=21 && textField.tag <36){
    if(textField.text.length != 0)
    [ingredients addObject:textField.text];
  }
}
```

So when the the text field has finished editing it adds its value into the mutable array. This all works perfectly fine. However my problem occurs if that text field is edited again, if the user changes the values in that text field it will then add another value into the array, i would like the previous value to be edited rather than creating a new value in the array.

Any help would be appreciated please!

Comment: why don't you add all textField values to array one time when User finish all the textFileds? Or do you have to do in this way?

Comment: You should use an NSDictionary to store a text value against a key in the dictionary depending on the tag of the UITextField, unless for whatever reason the solution is dependent on using an array.  See @JDx idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your ingredients object from NSMutableArray to NSMutableDictionary. Example:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    if(textField.tag >=21 && textField.tag <36){
        if(textField.text.length != 0)
            [ingredients setObject:textField.text forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:textField.tag]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks!Incase anyone else had any similar problems, once it fills the dictionary, the items are accessed like so:    `for(id key in ingredient) {
    id value = [ingredients objectForKey:key];
    [value doStuff];
}`

Answer (score 0):

When you're initialising, add 15 empty strings to your ingredients array. Then when `textFieldDidEndEditing:` is called, set the string at the appropriate index `(textField.tag - 21)` instead of using `addObject:`